# Remove Gesture Listener from a view in activity

Tags: android, swipe, seekbar, gesturedetector

I have a requirement to change the activity on swiping it either left or right.

For achieving this I use this [link](http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118) and complete my task. Now I have a problem whereas the activity also has a seek-bar that needs to swipe in either direction to change its position. Currently, whenever I move the thumb of the seek-bar the gesture listener of activity get activated and changes the Screen.

So How could I remove the listener from the seek-bar?

Comment: Without posting some code we cannot help you

Comment: I have coded exactly like example link given above and added a seek-bar view on the screen only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled this scenario by adding a hack.

Actually I disabled the gesture listener whenever user start moving thumb and enable it again when user leave it. Hope it helps someone having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change between several views by swiping left and right, I suggest that each of the activity you currently have, you transform them into fragments, and then have a container activity which will host a viewpager. This way, all the swiping is handled for you, and your seekbar will still work.

Comment: Actually all my activities also have child activity upto 2-3 levels, so is it possible to move into the child activity using same view pager. If yes can you please provide a link which I can refer?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have 3 levels of activities, and all are swipable left right?